# Date formatter numbers to text

Tags: java, android, date, date-format

I have the date format as "dd/MM/yyyy", i would like to convert this into MM DD, yyy an example:

```
10/10/1996 -> Oct 10, 1996
```

Also the other way around case:

```
  Oct 10, 1996 -->   10/10/1996
```

I have been trying for 1+ hour but couldnt figure it out as i have never used a date formatter class, if anyone could help me it would be awesome, PL: java

Comment: Please review the duplicate link.  If you actually try something and get stuck, then edit your question.

Comment: For most purposes, rather than converting your strings back and forth between date formats you should keep your date in a `LocalDate` variable and only format it into one or the other string format for display or serialization, the latter typically for transmission or storage. For not-brand-new Android add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to be able to use `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate`  and the other classes from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time, Parsing and Formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html) (that’s a link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Use these imports

```
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
```

Use this code to convert your date format from one to another:

```
         String fromDateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
         String fromdate = 15/03/2018; //Take any date

         String CheckFormat = "dd MMM yyyy";//take another format like dd/MMM/yyyy
         String dateStringFrom;

         Date DF = new Date();


          try
          {
             //DateFormatdf = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
             DateFormat FromDF = new SimpleDateFormat(fromDateFormat);
             FromDF.setLenient(false);  // this is important!
             Date FromDate = FromDF.parse(fromdate);
             dateStringFrom = new 
             SimpleDateFormat(CheckFormat).format(FromDate);
             DateFormat FromDF1 = new SimpleDateFormat(CheckFormat);
             DF=FromDF1.parse(dateStringFrom);
             System.out.println(dateStringFrom);
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {

              System.out.println("Date error");

          }
```

Note: Change your SimpleDateFormat accordingly.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class as the first option and without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming your'e using `DateTime`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date now = new Date();
String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
```

This code will format a DateTime to string as 2018-04-07.
You can play around with the format as you want. search for list of the format keys (such as MM, as I mentioned here).

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class as the first option and without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: @OleV.V. Agreed.